# How can I remove the Server from the email form "from" field?

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a basic form created.

When the user fills and sends the form, in my client's email inbox it comes in FROM my server name.

I have been looking through the code where I can edit this, but I am more designer than programmer.

What should I be looking for?

Thanks so much

Comment: You should share some of the relevant code

Comment: Can you give us the PHP code which is sending the mail ?

Answer (score 3):

you can only setup a name "displayed" to the receiver first. If the receiver looks into the message-header he will still see the origin (your server).

This is the usual snippet for this (see $headers)

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP function you need to set the "From" in the header

```
mail("me@domain.com" "Subject", "Body", "From: sender@domain.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

In the aditional headers you can add the `From` header, for example:

```
mail("user@domain.com", "Test", "message", "From: user@domain.com BCC:friend@domain.com")
```

Also, you can change the Default `From` header in the `php.ini` if my memory doesn't fail.